# KendoUI Grid Export just the table to PDF

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a KendoUI Grid I want to export to PDF, but the built in export functionality exports the complete element, including styles, toolbars, and navigation buttons.

Is it possible to just export the data, in a plain old table? The Excel export functionality does something similar already, just exporting the data.

Or would I have to hide all other elements and remove all the styles manually?

Comment: I would try the iTextSharp library to create your PDF. I had the same issues with the Kendo export and in the end I used iTextSharp and built the pdf from the ground up. It was easy and the library is very well documented and supported.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm using the HTML5/JS version of Kendo with a PHP backend, not .NET